# Python Selenium Upload a file via Windows Upload

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, file-upload

I read a lot about and everyone advice to don't use the Windows Upload and write directly the path of my file; I even try to use some command found in the forum like:

```
swicthTo()
switch_to_window()
window_handles
```

but I didn't find any solution yet.
My main problem is that time I have no space to send directly the path of my file (see image below, the space to introduce the path is grey-out) but I have only the option to click in "Browse" and open the Windows Uploader:

[image]

Do you know how can I switch to the upload window's Windows and introduce my fie?

I try even in this way:

```
browse=wait(".//*[@id='fileinput']") #open the window upload
browse.click()
time.sleep(1)


def handle_dialog(element_initiating_dialog, dialog_text_input):
    upload_dialog = driver.switch_to_active_element
    print (upload_dialog)
    upload_dialog.send_keys(dialog_text_input)
    upload_dialog.send_keys(selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER) # the ENTER key closes the upload dialog, other thread exits

handle_dialog(browse, "foobar.txt")
```

I find the windows and when I print I have this object:

```
We are already in the Location->Details Page <bound method WebDriver.switch_to_active_element of <selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver.WebDriver (session="3e725bb7-40a7-452a-ad90-9cca1d41296a")>>
```

But after when I try to do send_keys I receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\carlo.agresta\Desktop\IE - iQsonar.py", line 149, in
>   
>       handle_dialog(browse, "foobar.txt")   File "C:\Users\carlo.agresta\Desktop\IE - iQsonar.py", line 145, in
>   handle_dialog
>       upload_dialog.send_keys(dialog_text_input) AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

I partially found a solution, I let behave my code as if the window upload is an alert so I do in this way:

```
browse=wait(".//*[@id='fileinput']")
browse.click()
time.sleep(1)

upload_dialog = driver.switch_to_alert()
print (upload_dialog)

upload_dialog.send_keys("C:\\Users\\carlo.agresta\\Desktop\\V4LabCredentials.csv")
```

Now my problem is that I can't accept accept and close the window :S any advice?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: You should not open the dialog at all. Because then it goes to the native OS window which Selenium cannot control. What you should do is change `browse.click()` to `browse.send_keys("<complete file path">)`

Comment: Yes I know but I don't have other option, the text box is grey out and I don't have any other way to select my file. So far I could open the dialog window and introduce my path, I'm getting crazy how to accept it because the command .accept() is not working and there are just 2 bottom "open" and "Cancel". other option to solve my issue? any advice?

Comment: manually when i arrive at this point, pressing ENTER I accept the windows/pop-up, so I try to let my script press the key ENTER but it's not working neither because it replace my path with a dot "." :S

Comment: Even if it is greyed, have you tried using `send_keys` ?

Comment: Yes I try, it's not working I can't really do anything there :S

Comment: What error do you get when you try to do the same?

Comment: I don't get any error but the key that I want send doesn't appear in the screen and when I click on submit say that there is no file selected... looks that I found the element and it has the method send_keys but seeing that it's grey-out doesn't really introduce my key and then pass automatically to the following step of the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use autoit
example code:

```
import autoit
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element( driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='upload_button']")).click().perform()
handle = "[CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]"
autoit.win_wait(handle, 60)
autoit.control_set_text(handle, "Edit1", "\\file\\path")
autoit.control_click(handle, "Button1")
```